# Text file I/O with fstream and ifstream

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, ofstream

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    ifstream is; 
    is.open(argv[1]);
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(argv[2]);
    char ch; 
    while (1) 
    { 
         ch = is.get();   // this is where test.txt is supposed
         outfile.put(ch); // to be copied to test2.txt
         if (is.eof()) 
             break; 
         cout << ch;  //this shows
    }

    is.close();
    outfile.close();

    ifstream outfile2;
    outfile2.open(argv[2]); 
    char ch2; 
    while (1)
    { 
       ch2 = outfile2.get(); 
       if (outfile2.eof()) 
         break; 
       cout << ch2;  //this doesnt
    }        
        outfile2.close();

        system("PAUSE"); 
        return 0; 
    }
```

I run it through cmd giving it 2 arguments test.txt test2.txt and it outputs what i       have written in test.txt in cmd but test2.txt remains empty for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me its not coming blank but with some extra appended characters. this is because you are writing the character which you got from the old file to the new one before checking eof().

the code for writing from one file to another should be changed as

```
while (1) 
    { 
         ch = is.get();
         if (is.eof()) 
             break; 
         outfile.put(ch);
         cout << ch;  //this shows
    }
```

Comment: Same thing happens for me...nothing in test2.txt

Comment: change the index from argv[1], argv[2] to argv[0], argv[1] along with the code change suggested above

Comment: the arguments that i pass must be in argv[1] and argv[2] right?

Comment: isnt argv[0] used for the program name or something like that?

Comment: okay right. i usually work on visual studio and on that it is working fine by replacing arguments with hard coded file names

Comment: Why are you writing a nullbyte to the end of the output file? Concerning `argv`, the first element is indeed the program name. Hardcoding the filenames helps avoiding any transmission errors there though. Or, *gasp*, actually checking if you succeeded to open the file? Wouldn't that be an interesting approach?

Comment: ohh updated my answer. i am a beginner in c++. talking about the efficient code you have written. even i could have sujjested that. Its just that i didn't want @AlexMoumoulidis put up more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the streamstate not just for eof() but also for failure. Also, after reading the last character, it wouldn't be uncommon if the streamstate was EOF even though the character was successfully read. Therefore, always try to read an element and if it succeeded, and only then, use the element:

```
ifstream in(argv[1]);
ofstream out(argv[2]);
char c;
while(in.get(c))
    out.put(c);
```

To make this really efficient, use this though:

```
out << in.rdbuf();
```

In any case, check the streamstate for success:

```
if(!in.eof())
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to read input file");
if(!out.flush())
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to write output file");
```

Comment: the program is running fine in visual studio but not using gcc. it's throwing "this program cannot be run in DOS mode"

Comment: Which program are you talking about?

Comment: @Alex code replaced with my snippet. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700102/this-program-cannot-be-run-in-dos-mode/16700247?noredirect=1#16700247

Comment: Saksham, please check where and to whom you are replying, I guess you didn't mean your message to show up in the context of my answer but either in that of the question or your answer.

Comment: Ok so ill do that only could you make an assumption on why whatever i have inside test.txt isnt copied in test2.txt although the program seems to run fine on cmd and it also outputs it?